# Detect Windows Server version 32/64-bit in CLI

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, 32-bit

What's the best and quickest way to detect whether you're running a 32 or 64-bit version of Windows Server from the command line?

(Cygwin is installed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A slightly quicker way would be to check for the existence of the %ProgramFiles(x86)% directory. If it exists then you're running 64-bit, if it doesn't exist then you're running 32-bit.

Quick one-liner:

```
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" echo 64-bit
```

That will output `64-bit` if the directory exists. That would fail, though, if it didn't exist as a variable but it did exist as a directory (as %ProgramFiles(x86)%).

You can also use the find tool to have a more accurate way to determine bitness.

```
set | find "ProgramFiles(x86)"
```

or using the `systeminfo` command previously

```
systeminfo | find /I "System type"
```

(included the `/I` to work across XP/2003/2008/etc)

Comment: it should be `systeminfo | find "System type"`  Capitol T returns nothing.

Comment: Yup, completely missed that. Thanks Nathan! Of course, you could also use the /I switch to make it case insensitive as well.

Comment: Server 2008, its actually a capital 'T'.

Either way. Thanks for the answer - perfect.

Comment: Fine! I went ahead and included the /I switch to systeminfo so that it'll find it whether it's a capital t or not! :)

Answer (score 22):

How about:

```
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
```

This will return **x86** on 32-bit systems and **AMD64** (or **IA64**) on 64-bit systems.

Comment: How comes this had 0 votes? o.O (+1)

Comment: This is a **much better solution** then checking for the existence of the `Program Files (x86)` directory as someone else posted.  You could *also* check for the existence of the `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` environment variable (if it *doesn't* exist, then you're on an x86 machine).

Comment: *> How comes this had 0 votes?*   Maybe because it is [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601089/detect-whether-current-windows-version-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) [reliable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx).

Comment: THIS  ANSWER HAS PROBLEMS!! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738985/why-processor-architecture-always-returns-x86-instead-of-amd64

Answer (score 9):

```
systeminfo
```

It will list quite a bit, about 10 fields down there is one called System Type. This will tell you if it's x86 or x64

Answer (score 8):

```
systeminfo | find /I "System type"
```

This is locale dependent, and **slow**.

```
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
```

Notice, that it's **x86** in 32-bit `cmd.exe`.

Correct way:

```
set Arch=x64
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" ( 
    if not defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 set Arch=x86
)
```

Comment: Completely agree on your thoughts on using 'systeminfo'. Thanks for your suggestion, I've used that in one of my scripts

Comment: The Best ANSWER! with additional validator `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432`

Answer (score 6):

Other way to check with a WMI query:

PowerShell:

```
(gwmi win32_computersystem).SystemType
```

CMD:

```
wmic OS get OSArchitecture
```

Extracted from here: http://www.sysadmit.com/2015/10/windows-como-saber-si-es-de-32-o-64-bits.html

Answer (score 5):

There are numerous ways to check the processor architecture under Windows:

- The fastest, easiest, and most compatible way to check the processor architecture in [at least Windows 2000](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc959490%28v=technet.10%29) and up is to examine the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` [environment variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details#environment_variables):

  `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`
- However, this can give different results, depending on the way in which the command-prompt is opened. To avoid getting [“unexpected results” due to WoW64](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201140747/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx), you can read it directly from the registry (Microsoft made no less than [two typos in the key](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215061908/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/556009)):

  `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`
- Microsoft also suggests reading the hardware information store from the registry:

  `reg query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" /v Identifier`
- You can also check for the existence of the x86 version of the `Program Files` directory (or the [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) that points to it) since it would only exist on a 64-bit system. Unlike the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` variable, this is not dependant on the way that the command prompt is run since the directory exists (or not) regardless of how the prompt is opened:

  - `::via env-var`
    `if not defined ProgramFiles(x86) echo 32-bit`
  - `::via file-system`
    `if not exist "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)" echo 32-bit`

These methods can be combined in a single batch-file (e.g., `cpuinfo.bat`) and provides a nice, lightning fast way to check the system from a standard Windows NT command-prompt without needing to resort to running other programs or frameworks.

This was tested on 32-bit and Intel 64-bit systems (please test on AMD64), giving correct results in <1 second:

```
@echo off

echo PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE var:
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% | find /i "x86" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE reg:
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE | find /i "x86" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo CentralProcessor reg:
reg query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo ProgramFiles(x86) var:
if not defined ProgramFiles(x86) (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo ProgramFiles(x86) dir:
if not exist "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)" (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.
```

Answer (score 3):

### GENERIC SOLUTION

I really had to dig into this and have a real look around in WMI.

The best option in my opinion is to simply use this PowerShell string

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).SystemType
```

This even work with old Windows 2003 and XP

The answer will be one of

- X86-based PC
- x64-based PC

x64-based PC

Or if reverting to some old fashioned cmd tools

```
wmic computersystem get systemtype
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not the ideal answer, and `systeminfo.exe` should be your preferred method of determining the system type, i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit, this solution runs a little faster if you do not want to wait for `systeminfo.exe` to finish its work.

The command:

```
reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" | find "BuildLabEx"
```

With the correct changes to the registry query and search string you can also check for operating system versions as far back as Windows 95. `systeminfo.exe` is more exact and the correct way of querying, `reg.exe query` is faster and more backwards compatible.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the edits, you removed important information to the answer, and then proceeded to actually introduce a bug.

Comment: Rather than piping the output through Microsoft's buggy "find" command, you can have REG.EXE pull the exact value with the /v switch:  `reg query "HKLM\[..as before..]\Version" /v BuildLabEx`

Answer (score 0):

## Better SOLUTION:

**Method 1:** 
(Two step Validation with `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` and `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432`)

```
set Arch=x64
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" ( 
    if not defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 set Arch=x86
) 


if %Arch% == "x64"  (
    msg * "yessss"
) else  (
    msg * "noooo"
)
```

**Method 2:**

```
reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x32" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

if %OS%==32BIT echo "YESSS"
if %OS%==64BIT echo "NOOO"
```

source: https://superuser.com/a/293143/249349

Answer (score -1):

Using the WMI interface, under the Command Prompt. Open the Command Prompt as Administrator, and type `wmic OS get OSArchitecture` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>