# Check if 32 or 64-bit Windows OS via registry

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windows-registry, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect Windows Server version 32/64-bit in CLI](https://superuser.com/questions/68452/detect-windows-server-version-32-64-bit-in-cli)

Is there a way to check whether a user is running a 64-bit or 32-bit operating system by looking in the registry?

The following site makes some suggestions:
http://www.maxi-pedia.com/32+Bit+or+64+Bit+Operating+System

But the suggestions of

> HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0

and

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentCongtrolSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\Envirornment

do not appear to exist in my registry

Comment: In what way do they not work?

Comment: Sorry. I've clarified that now.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you on?

Comment: I'd like it to be generic across all windows versions.

Comment: @Gareth. This is certainly NOT a duplicate. I need to detect 32/64 bit VIA THE REGISTRY.

Comment: I just checked it - it's present in both my XP (x32) and 7 (x64) PC's windows registry. Which key in the registry is the first you can't find?

Comment: from the linked duplicate - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` - check for `BuildLabEx`

Comment: @Sathya. Cool that's what I was after.

Comment: @Urbycoz - apols. It might not have been an exact duplicate but at least you got your answer from there anyway. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registry key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\BuildLabEx
```

should give you the required info

Comment: And what should the value be for 32 bit versus 64 bit ?

Comment: this key does not exist on my windows 10 box