# Determine 32bit/64bit from powershell script inside Inno Setup

Tags: 64-bit, powershell

Consider the following powershell script:

```
[System.IntPtr]::Size
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

If I run this directly inside powershell on a 64bit machine, then I correctly get

```
8
True
```

But when I wrap this inside a self-extracting installer using Inno Setup (that is built on a 32bit machine) I always get:

```
4
False
```

How do I make sure powershell is running in 64bit mode when on a 64bit computer (and 32bit for 32bit computer)?

I have also tried executing a batch file which calls the powershell script, assuming that the system would start powershell in its default mode, but this also doesn't work.

I have also tried iexpress to wrap the program, same problem.

Comment: Your going about this problem the wrong way.  Create two setups one 32-bit one 64-bit then dont worry about what platform since you will already know the platform

Comment: Have you tried checking the registry? According to this answer ( http://superuser.com/questions/290906/check-if-32-or-64-bit-windows-os-via-registry ) you can check the value of "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\BuildLabEx"

Comment: It may be more useful to check, if you still wish to be checking for this, in the registry as @Curtis mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your installer is a 32bit Application, it will always start a 32bit PowerShell. Even using the full path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

because the Windows File system redirector will change it to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

to start a 64bit PowerShell from a 32bit process, use:

```
C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

on a 32bit machine, the same command should still execute the 32bit PowerShell, but I can't test that anymore.