# How do I determine if my Windows is 32-bit or 64-bit using a command?

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to tell if a computer has a 64-bit CPU or OS](https://superuser.com/questions/208312/how-to-tell-if-a-computer-has-a-64-bit-cpu-or-os)
>   [Detect Windows Server version 32/64-bit in CLI](https://superuser.com/questions/68452/detect-windows-server-version-32-64-bit-in-cli)
>   [OS version: 32-bit or 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/96092/os-version-32-bit-or-64-bit)

How do I determine if my Windows system is 32-bit or 64-bit from the commandline?

I want to know the bitness of the operating system, not the hardware.

This question applies strictly to **command line only**, I don't want any GUI solutions.

Comment: Hmm, it's sad that `systeminfo` does not list this.

Comment: @MaQleod - I'd personally argue that just because your answer suits both, that the questions aren't exact duplicates because this one is a much more specific scenario.  I don't know if your answer quite fits 'command line only' since it needs an extra utility, but if it were me I'd post it as an answer here.

Comment: @MaQleod I personally wouldn't call it a duplicate since it's asking for a specifically command-line only solution. The question you linked has an accepted answer for a GUI solution.

Comment: Thank you for the edit + answers.  I chose the answer that best suited my situation.

Comment: I ended up finding what IS an exact duplicate of this.  (Linked post specifically references command-line only, and even provides my exact solution.)

Comment: Use  : `uname -a` for linux system , Did u see how it is so simple with linux ? if so ,  delete windows and install linux

Answer (score 148, accepted):

From an elevated command prompt, type `wmic os get osarchitecture`.  The output is pretty obvious, I think - it'll return either "32-bit" or "64-bit".

Comment: This sounds like the solution I'd use... Now that I know of it.

Comment: Or to do the same thing in Powershell if you are on a W7 machine or another windows OS where you have installed PS:  (gwmi win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture

Comment: Not working here on Windows XP. Returns Error: Invalid query.

Comment: Caveat: **must** be an administrator to run WMIC.

Comment: @user606723 - I don't have an XP install handy to test on, but I didn't think the WMI hooks had changed that much.  OP did not specify an OS, to be fair, but I'll have to test this myself.

Comment: @Breakthrough - You're right, I should be explicit about this.

Comment: wmic is not recognized as an internal or external command....

Comment: If the output is too long you can optionally find it via `wmic os | findstr "64-bit"` or `wmic os | findstr "32-bit"`

Comment: As suggested, the correct query is: `wmic os get osarchitecture`

Answer (score 67):

The systeminfo console program will show this. You will want to look for the "System Type:" line. For 32-bit systems, it will say "x86-based PC'. For 64-bit systems, it will say "x64-based PC".

Or, for a quicker method, you can simply check the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable. 64-bit systems will say AMD64 and 32-bit systems should say "x86". To check this you can simply echo it out:

```
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
```

David Wang over at MSDN Blogs expands upon this [HOWTO: Detect Process Bitness](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/howto-detect-process-bitness)

Comment: Doesn't this show the PROCESSOR type, not the installed OS type?

Comment: I don't think so, because 32-bit mode and 64-bit mode are different modes the processor could be in. A processor could be in 32-bit mode, and I don't think the OS would know inherently if it could transition into 64-bit mode. However, it's a good point, it's something that would have to be tested. As I know my brother has a 32-bit Win 7 install on a 64-bit capable processor, I'll ask him to check for me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure (hence the tentative response) and unfortunately don't have anything handy to check on myself.  I thought this was just a string that a given processor reported back, regardless of how it's functioning.  It would be helpful to know for sure.

Comment: If you run a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit system, %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% will still be "x86".  In most cases, a 64-bit OS can run 32-bit programs, but this does *not* work the other way around.

Comment: @bobbymcr - Thanks for confirmation, in that case I retract my objection.

Comment: This is the by far the best answer.

Comment: up vote as **echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%**
 works even in sql server command shell too.where as **wmic os get osarchitecture** sometime's doesn't work in sql server command shell

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for on my Windows XP machine, will greatly help me with scripting projects

Comment: +1 as this solution does not require admin rights, whereas the accepted answer does

Answer (score 10):

You can check if the `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%` environment variable is declared.  On 32-bit systems, it will *not* be defined (only `%PROGRAMFILES%` will be).  This is also safer then just checking if the Program Files (x86) directory exists, since it can be moved (or even deleted).

Comment: Better workaround than checking for the folder, yeah.  (I don't like using a workaround, but if you're going to this is the one to use.)

Comment: Very good catch... I have a batch that checks for the folder, but this would definitely be more elegant.

Comment: You can also compare the `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%` and `%PROGRAMFILES%` variables to see if the cmd has been started in 32bit or 64bit mode. (Because on a 64 bit windows you can still run a 32bit cmd.) Example:

IF `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%` == `%PROGRAMFILES%` => 32bit cmd (that is running on a 64 bit windows.....)

IF `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%` <> `%PROGRAMFILES%` => 64bit cmd.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a simple command line application that will tell you whether your processor and your OS are either 64-bit or 32-bit.

Readout example:

```
C:\bitchecker
The CPU is 64-bit and the OS is 32-bit
```

Per request, here is the source, compiled using CLI option, written in AutoIt.

```
If @CPUARCH = "x86" Then
    $CPUARCH = "32-bit"
Else
    $CPUARCH = "64-bit"
EndIf

If @OSARCH = "x86" Then
    $OSARCH = "32-bit"
Else
    $OSARCH = "64-bit"
EndIf

ConsoleWrite("The CPU is " & $CPUARCH & " and the OS is " & $OSARCH)
```

And here is an example if you want switches for CPU (-c) and OS (-o):

```
Dim $CPUARCH, $OSARCH

If @CPUARCH = "x86" Then
    $CPUARCH = "32-bit"
Else
    $CPUARCH = "64-bit"
EndIf

If @OSARCH = "x86" Then
    $OSARCH = "32-bit"
Else
    $OSARCH = "64-bit"
EndIf

If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then
    ConsoleWrite("The CPU is " & $CPUARCH & " and the OS is " & $OSARCH)
Else
    Select
        Case $CmdLine[1] = "-c"
            ConsoleWrite($CPUARCH)
        Case $CmdLine[1] = "-o"
            ConsoleWrite($OSARCH)
        Case Else
            ConsoleWrite("The CPU is " & $CPUARCH & " and the OS is " & $OSARCH)
    EndSelect
EndIf
```

Comment: I'd be nice if the file came with source. It's rather unnerving to download an small exe, posted to mediafire, and to run it.

Comment: @artifex, added source.

Comment: it could be false U_U

Jocking :)

Comment: It would be nice to know what API autoit is using internally..

Answer (score 4):

What if you just check for the presence of

> %SYSTEMROOT%\Program Files(x86)

or whatever it's called?

Comment: Not a super solution, but maybe quick and dirty works for your particular problem?

Comment: You beat me to this solution, +1. A short form could be `dir \Program *`.